# Links on Firefox and IE floating away on mouse over

Tags: css, hyperlink

I'm creating a new design for my website but since a couple of day I'm fighting with something that I'm not able to find :-)
after I finished my CSS and put online, it works properly on Google Chrome but if I check the pages on IE or Firefox I'm not able to click on any link because on mouse over it float away..
I spent all day looking for the mistake but unfortunately I can't understat what is generating this...
Could anyone here help me to find the problem?

Thank you very much for your help!

check the website at http://www.empirestate.it
CSS at: http://www.empirestate.it/CSS/template.css

Comment: works fine on Firefox v23

Comment: Same here, and in IE. In Chrome however, two entries in the "Turismo" dropdown overlap each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, thanks for your help... i solved the problem...a class declared 2 times with different float, no problem with chrome that was using hover correctly, that's why it was working properly only on that browser.

THanks Mr Lister, i will work to solve the overlap on the dropdown menu.